# C string functions error

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I'm working on an assignment, but I'm having trouble with my code :

```
int is_ascii_match(const char c1[], const char c2[], char res[MAX_STRING_SIZE]) {
....

    if (val_c1 == val_c2) {
        strcpy(res, strcat(strcat(c1, '&'),c2));
    }
    else
        return 0;
```

I'm getting an error :

> Access violation reading location

Do I pass the parameters wrong or..?

Comment: Are the calculation and values of `val_c1` and `val_c2` relevant to your question? If no, why include these lines? If yes, what are they?

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that a user of your reputation doesn't know about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's because I assumed the error has something to do with the arrguments I pass in the String functions, and it doesn't seems like any other info is neccesary @Beta , Still new to C though, so maybe I'm wrong .

Comment: Don't ignore compiler's diagnostic messages. The compiler, I'm sure, informed you about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat` expects a non-const `char*`. You passed a `const` that's why compiler complained.

Also the second parameter would be `"&"`. (Earlier you passed a `char`).

From standard §7.24.3.1

```
char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2`
>   (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string
>   pointed to by `s1`.

So `s1` will be modified (the first parameter) that's why it should be non-const.

Comment: Thanks, I'll approve when possible :)

Comment: That doesn't look right. Are you talking about the outer `strcat` or the inner one? Which argument is const when it ought to be non-const?

Comment: @Beta.: The first one which will be modified.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I misread the question. I could have sworn that `c1` was declared non-const.

Comment: @Beta.: It's alright no need to be sorry. Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 0):

`'&'` is a character literal, which is a small integer. The second argument of `strcat` is a `const char*`, which is a pointer to a character (more precisely, a pointer to the first character in a contiguous NUL-terminated array of `char`s). 
You presumably intended `"&"`, which is a two-byte array.

Attempting to interpret a small integer as a pointer leads to precisely the problem indicated by the error.

If it were not for the problem reading the second argument, you might be presented with an error when `strcat` attempts to modify the string pointed to by its first argument, which is `const` and thus conceivably in read-only memory. (Modifying the first argument seems semantically incorrect, as well.)

If you compile with warnings enabled, you should see a warning about the types of the argument.

For this particular problem, consider the use of `snprintf(res, MAX_STRING_SIZE, "%s&%s", c1, c2)`, which avoids modifying `c1` and protects against buffer overflow. (You should compare the return value with `MAX_STRING_SIZE` if you care about truncation.)